# \begin{align*} ... \end{align*} is not working

Tags: align

I am getting an error in the following code on my LaTeX template. But the same code is running on MathJax.

```
\begin{align*}
    1. {\log_{a}a} = 1\  \mbox{log of a number to the same base is 1}

\end{align*}
```

Please help.

Comment: You shouldn't have an empty line in `align*` and you need to load `amsmath` (with `\usepackage{amsmath}` or another package that loads it) to be able to use it. Remember: MathJax is not LaTeX.

Comment: To make this code compile, remove the blank line.

Comment: Why is `\log_{a}a` encased in curly braces?

Comment: MathJax is forgiving about blank lines, LaTeX isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is due to the blank line, but also do not use `align` or `align*` for 1-line equations with no alignment, the vertical spacing will be wrong. If the 1. is not mathematics but part of an enumerated list then perhaps

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item $\log_{a}a = 1$ log of a number to the same base is $1$
\end{enumerate}
```